# How can i save a Image in Internal Storage of android device?

Tags: android, save

I want to save an image in the device's internal storage because many devices do not have external storage or SD Card.

```
InputStream y11 = getResources().openRawResource(to);
Bitmap b11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(y11);
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + "/newimages");

direct.mkdirs();

String fName = "Image-" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+ ".jpg";
File file = new File(direct, fName);
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
try {

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

b11.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

out.flush();
// out.close();
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: This is my programming question only. This code helps me to save image in sdCard only. But what if device dose not has sdCard? This code is not working for that. So what is the solution?

Comment: "This code helps me to save image in sdCard only" -- no, it saves the image to external storage. External storage is not an "sdCard". "But what if device dose not has sdCard?" -- just about all Android devices have external storage. That being said, you can save the image on internal storage, using `getFilesDir()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to check if SD-CARD exists:

```
Boolean haveSd= android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(haveSd)
{
  // Work on device-sd
}
else
{
  //Work on device
}
```

And the if you want save in internal storage:

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {

   try {
   // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
   // the OutputStream
   FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
   image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
   fos.close();

   return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
     return false;
   }
}
```